# Trying to retrieve checkbox value from form

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a form with a checkbox group that is loaded from a table. The table fields are MySQL TINYINT fields that hold a 1 for true and 0 for false, and are named thusly: `frequency_sun`, `frequency_mon`, `frequency_tue`, `frequency_wed`, `frequency_thu`, `frequency_fri`, `frequency_sat`.

The form is set up this way:

```
    <?php
$checked = ($frequency_sun==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[sun]' value=".$frequency_sun." >Sunday";
$checked = ($frequency_mon==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[mon]' value=".$frequency_mon." >Monday";
$checked = ($frequency_tue==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[tue]' value=".$frequency_tue." >Tuesday";
$checked = ($frequency_wed==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[wed]' value=".$frequency_wed." >Wednesday";
$checked = ($frequency_thu==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[thu]' value=".$frequency_thu." >Thursday";
$checked = ($frequency_fri==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[fri]' value=".$frequency_fri." >Friday";
$checked = ($frequency_sat==1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
                    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\"" . $checked . "name='frequency[sat]' value=".$frequency_sat." >Saturday";
                    ?>
```

I suspect that part of this is unnecessary and/or clumsy, but that's not my main problem-at least not immediately.
Anyway, the checkbox group is being loaded correctly. I'm trying to retrieve the form data by setting a variable to the `$_POST` data:

```
$frequency = $_POST['frequency'];
```

// and then I'm setting variables to be used in a SQL UPDATE like this:

```
$frequency_sun = (isset($frequency['sun']) ? $frequency['sun'] : $frequency_sun);
$frequency_mon = (isset($frequency['mon']) ? $frequency['mon'] : $frequency_mon);
$frequency_tue = (isset($frequency['tue']) ? $frequency['tue'] : $frequency_tue);
$frequency_wed = (isset($frequency['wed']) ? $frequency['wed'] : $frequency_wed);
$frequency_thu = (isset($frequency['thu']) ? $frequency['thu'] : $frequency_thu);
$frequency_fri = (isset($frequency['fri']) ? $frequency['fri'] : $frequency_fri);
$frequency_sat = (isset($frequency['sat']) ? $frequency['sat'] : $frequency_sat);
```

which doesn't seem to return a value when a specific checkbox is checked. For my test, I've set `frequency_wed` in the table to 0 and want to set it to 1, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: checkbox reports `on` when they are checked.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your coding way, you can do something like this

```
<?
    if($frequency_sun == 1) $checked_sun = 'checked="checked"';
    if($frequency_mon == 1) $checked_mon = 'checked="checked"';
    if($frequency_tue == 1) $checked_tue = 'checked="checked"';
    if($frequency_wed == 1) $checked_wed = 'checked="checked"';
    if($frequency_thu == 1) $checked_thu = 'checked="checked"';
    if($frequency_fri == 1) $checked_fri = 'checked="checked"';
    if($frequency_sat == 1) $checked_sat = 'checked="checked"';
?>    

    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[sun]' value="<?=$frequency_sun?>" <?=$checked_sun?> />Sunday<br />
    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[mon]' value="<?=$frequency_mon?>" <?=$checked_mon?> />Monday<br />
    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[tue]' value="<?=$frequency_tue?>" <?=$checked_tue?> />Tuesday<br />
    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[wed]' value="<?=$frequency_wed?>" <?=$checked_wed?> />Wednesday<br />
    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[thu]' value="<?=$frequency_thu?>" <?=$checked_thu?> />Thursday<br />
    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[fri]' value="<?=$frequency_fri?>" <?=$checked_fri?> />Friday<br />
    <input type="chexkbox" name='frequency[sat]' value="<?=$frequency_sat?>" <?=$checked_sat?> />Saturday<br />
```

next, you need to get the values from your frequency array

```
$frequency = $_POST['frequency'];
$frequency_sun = $frequency['sun'];
"UPDATE yourtable SET sunday = '$frequency_sun', ..... WHERE something = 'value'";
```

Then you select

```
"SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE something = 'value'"
```

And finally your values

```
$frequency_sun = $query_result['sunday'];
.
.
.
```

Of course, you need to get values from your database BEFORE the form.

Comment: I've made myself a little sign, to wit: IF YOUR DESIGN PROBLEM CAN BE ANSWERED WITH 'YES' OR 'NO' AND NOTHING ELSE, USE A BLOODY RADIO BUTTON. Thank you all for trying to help a poor fool with blinders on, and I'm sorry anyone had to put up with this. Now let us never speak of this again...

Comment: Could you solve it? if Yes, edit your question and set it SOLVED with your answer if mine was not.

Comment: Bleah. Yes, I'll mark it solved. I retained checkboxes because although only boolean values are being stored, more than one selection might apply. I hard-coded values for the checkboxes('value=1' for Sunday, 'value=2' for Monday, and so on) and then just test to see whether they're checked or not; if checked, store a 1, otherwise store a 0. I will have an issue with ferreting out boxes that haven't been checked but that's another issue. Thank you again for your assistance.